# Nifi-Loading XML data into Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am trying to insert XML data into Cassandra DB. Please can somebody suggest the flow in nifi. I have JMS on which I need to post messagedata  and then consume & insert the data into Cassandra.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can directly ingest XML into Cassandra. However you could convert the XML to JSON using the [TransformXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html) processor (and [this XSLT](https://github.com/bramstein/xsltjson/blob/master/conf/xml-to-json.xsl)), or as of NiFi 1.2.0, you can use [ConvertRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ConvertRecord/index.html) by specifying the input and output schemas.

If there are multiple XML records per flow file and you need one CQL statement per record, you may need [SplitJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html) or [SplitRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitRecord/index.html) after the XML-to-JSON conversion has taken place.

Then you can use ReplaceText to form a CQL statement to [insert the JSON](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useInsertJSON.html), then [PutCassandraQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cassandra-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.PutCassandraQL/index.html) to push to Cassandra. Alternatively you can use [CQL map syntax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html) to insert into a map field, etc.

Comment: Thank You  , While trying to insert data in to cassendra i am getting Error in PutCassendraQL "No viable alternative at input '{' .Please suggest what might be the reason for this and how to fix this .  My relacementtext processor have this entries Search Value : (?s:(^.*)$)
Replacement Value : $1
Character Set : UTF-8
Maximum Buffer Size :1 MB
Replacement Strategy : Regex Replace
Evaluation Mode :Entire text