# Nifi - No Viable alternative @ Input '{'

Tags: apache-nifi

While trying to insert XML data in to Cassendra DB using apache Nifi, I am getting the below error. What's going wrong?

> Error : "No Viable alternative at Input '{'

Below are my ReplaceText Processor entries:

```
Search Value : (?s:(^.*)$)
Replacement Value : $1
Character Set : UTF-8
Maximum Buffer Size :1 MB
Replacement Strategy :Regex Replace
Evaluation Mode :Entire text
```

Comment: Please provide the full configuration of the flow, a complete stacktrace from the `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file, some sample data that is failing, and explain your goal for the flow.

Answer (score 0):

PutCassandraQL expects the input to be a valid CQL statement. If you have JSON in the content (presumably you are following my suggestions from [your other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283929/nifi-loading-xml-data-in-to-cassendra/45285010#45285010)), you need to create a CQL statement with JSON as the "payload", such as using ReplaceText with the following Replacement Value:

```
INSERT INTO myTable JSON '$1'
```

If the previous flow file contains a JSON object (and has no single quotes or they are escaped), this should create a valid CQL statement from it, for use in PutCassandraQL.